# How do I implement sliding window algorithm on an image?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm making the Super Mario Bros. game on python using the pygame library. I wanted to fit only a portion of the map of mario bros level and I have no idea how am I supposed to do that. One of my seniors told me that I could use the sliding window algorithm. However, the problem is I don't know how to implement this algorithm on the image. If I can get any help that would be really appreciated.[mario level world 1-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUfIi.png)
I have also been able to print out the map to a suitable scaling:
[map on code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOuD6.png)

edit: I am sorry I did not post my code. here it is:

```
import pygame
import pygame.transform 
i = pygame.init()

X = 640
Y = 480
Window = pygame.display.set_mode ((X, Y))
pygame.display.set_caption ("Game")
Mario_Standing_Left = pygame.image.load("F:\\Mario in Python\\Mario_Standing_Left.png")
Mario_Standing_Right = pygame.image.load("F:\\Mario in Python\\Mario_Standing_Right.png")
x = 50
y = 430
width = 40
height = 60
speed = 5
isjump = False
jumpcount = 10
left = False
right = False
WalkCount = 0

ScreenWidth = X - width - speed
ScreenHeight = Y - height - speed
isjump = False
jumpcount = 10
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay (50) #time in pygame measured in milliseconds
    
    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > speed:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x <= ScreenWidth:
        x += speed
    if not (isjump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True 
    else:
        if jumpcount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpcount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpcount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpcount -= 1
        else:
            isjump = False
            jumpcount = 10
    Window.fill ((0,0,0))
    
     #(surface, (the window defined above, (colour), (the object being drawn)))
    pygame.display.update()
    
    world = pygame.image.load('World 1-1.png').convert()
    world = pygame.transform.smoothscale(world,(8750,1400))
    while True:
        Window.blit(world,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.display.quit()
                
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you

Comment: the simplest can be create big Surface to draw all world and later display in window only some part of this Surface.

Comment: @furas that is exactly what I'm trying to do. But the thing is this is my first time working on a game, and on pygame. I am confused how am I supposed to do that. My current guess is that i can use the pygame.transform.chop function and cut the window into small parts. If I could get any help regarding my problem I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: you should use [pygame.Surface((width, height))](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to create place for all world. And later you copy on screen only some `area` of this world using `window.blit(world, area=...)`

Comment: BTW: you could crop and resize image in some Image Editor before you use it in game.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `area` in `blit(..., area=...)` to display only some part of `world`

I use `area = pygame.Rect(0, 300, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)` to keep information what area to display. And I change `area.x` to scroll it right and left.

```
import pygame

# --- constants  ---  # PEP8: all constants directly after imports

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 60

# --- main ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode ((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

world_image = pygame.image.load('World 1-1.png').convert()
world_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(world_image, (8750,1400))

world_rect = world_image.get_rect()

area = pygame.Rect(0, 300, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)

direction = 'right'

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True

while run:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if direction == 'right':
        # move right
        area.x += 2
        # change direction
        if area.right > world_rect.right:
            area.right = world_rect.right
            direction = 'left'
    else:
        # move left
        area.x -= 2
        # change direction
        if area.left < world_rect.left:
            area.left = world_rect.left
            direction = 'right'
        
    #window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    window.blit(world_image, (0,0), area=area)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    clock.tick(FPS)  # keep speed 60 FPS (Frames Per Second)
        
# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

If you will have other elements then you may need to create `Surface` with size of world to blit `world` and other elements before on this surface and later display it in `window` using `area`.

```
import pygame

# --- constants  ---

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 60

# --- main ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode ((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
window_rect = window.get_rect()

world_image = pygame.image.load('World 1-1.png').convert()
world_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(world_image, (8750,1400))
world_rect = world_image.get_rect()

player_image = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
player_image.fill((255, 0, 0)) # red
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(centerx=window_rect.centerx, centery=window_rect.centery+300 )

area = pygame.Rect(0, 300, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
direction = 'right'

buffer = pygame.Surface(world_rect.size)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if direction == 'right':
        # move right
        area.x += 5
        player_rect.x += 5
        # change direction
        if area.right > world_rect.right:
            area.x -= 5
            player_rect.x -= 5
            #area.right = world_rect.right
            direction = 'left'
    else:
        # move left
        area.x -= 5
        player_rect.x -= 5
        # change direction
        if area.left < world_rect.left:
            area.x += 5
            player_rect.x += 5
            #area.left = world_rect.left
            direction = 'right'

    #player_rect.center = area.center

    buffer.blit(world_image, (0,0))
    buffer.blit(player_image, player_rect)
    
    # ---
    
    #window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    window.blit(buffer, (0,0), area=area)
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    clock.tick(FPS)  # keep speed 60 FPS (Frames Per Second)
        
# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the need for writing area=area in the window blit?

Comment: if I would use `selected_area = pygame.Rect(...)` then it would be `area=selected_area`. Of course you could use it without `area=` as `blit(buffer, (0,0), selected_area)` but I would like to show that 3th parameter is assigned to variabel `area=` (which you can see in [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)